# Tag merge request: [wildcard] and [wildcards]

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There are <s>245</s> [246](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972733/how-do-i-delete-files-that-do-not-match-the-wildcard) questions tagged [wildcard](/questions/tagged/wildcard), and 53 with [wildcards](/questions/tagged/wildcards). I suggest the latter to be the main tag, and the former to be a synonym.