# Pending tag synonyms are undiscoverable

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

I just ran across [a complaint on Meta.Christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/help-with-tag-synonyms-please/1062#1062) that there were several pending tag synonyms that had been sitting around for quite a while without ever getting approved.  I was a bit surprised to see that, as it was the first I'd heard of it.

StackExchange's interface has spoiled me, I guess.  When there's pending business that requires some sort of attention, it shows up in the bar along the top of the page.  But we don't get that for tag synonyms, which I think is why no one noticed until a user called attention to them.  Could we get them added to the set of things that we get notifications about, for mods and any users with enough rep?

Comment: On Physics we've created a meta-thread for advertising synonyms.

Comment: IMO they should ping every user eligible to vote on them.

Comment: This specific suggestion that _might_ address the [more general](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127459/1438) problem.