# Tag Synonym decay

Tags: feature-request, flags, tag-synonyms

I've been playing around in the tag wiki/tag synonym area recently on SO, and tried to combine recommend the tag [flashbuilder](/questions/tagged/flashbuilder) --> [flash-builder](/questions/tagged/flash-builder) synonym. Imagine my surprise, when I saw...

[image: already proposed]

With the help of a little search box, I discovered:

[image: old tag synonym]

These tag synonym requests

1. Are old.
2. Have Low vote count / no vote count.
3. Are (in my opinion) incorrect. [flexbuilder](/questions/tagged/flexbuilder) is the *old* name of [flash-builder](/questions/tagged/flash-builder), and questions pertaining to one may not pertain to the other.

I would like to leave [flexbuilder](/questions/tagged/flexbuilder) alone, but I would also like to propose the synonym stated above.

As I do not have a score of 5 in flexbuilder, I cannot even vote these down, in the hopes that someone else in the future finishes them off. However, that's a completely different issue.

1. Is there any method by which tag synonym requests decay?
2. If not, can it be implemented?
3. Or can we get a 'flag for moderator attention' button on tag synonyms?

Comment: Related discussion: [Does the tag synonym suggestion system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127459)