# Tag Synonym - Score of 5 Rule Amendment

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

As mentioned in [this other meta question I just raised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128982/166938), I had some issues with the tag synonym process earlier.

Currently, a user can only recommend or vote on a tag synonym if they have a 'Score of 5' in the 'Master' tag.

I feel that this rule could be amended, in order to allow better management of tags by conscientious users who may not participate in questions regarding a certain tag, but like to help maintain the tag system.

I would recommend the following changes:

1. Allow a user with a Score of 5 in the intended 'Synonym' tag to propose a tag synonym.
2. Allow a user with a Score of 5 in the intended 'Synonym' tag to vote on a tag synonym request.

Comment: These would be helpful changes, but I think they do not address the more [general issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127459/does-the-tag-synonym-suggestion-system-work): the tag synonym suggestion system doesn't seem to result in new synonyms.  Moderators almost always have to step in to make the change.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128147/tag-synonym-voting-set-score-threshold-as-the-sum-of-scores-on-the-synonym-and Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79151/add-the-ability-to-create-any-tag-synonym-to-the-trusted-user-privileges

Comment: I don't see any reason to require any score in the tag at all. Users who have enough reputation to suggest tag synonyms usually know what they're doing, and even if they don't, it's just a suggestion so it will get rejected if it's a bad suggestion.