# Create tag synonym between "newline" and "line-breaks"?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

I noticed that these two tags exist:

- [line-breaks](/questions/tagged/line-breaks)
- [newline](/questions/tagged/newline)

Both of them really just seem to be about any kinds of line breaks. So I thought, since I have 5000 reputation, let's propose a synonym. But then I saw that I also needed a score of 5 in one of them. So I retagged an appropriate question I had answered with a score of 7 (I will probably get scolded for this, but I just wanted to clean up the tags a bit) with "line-breaks". Then when I tried to propose the synonym, I could not because "newline" has more than 1.25 times the amount of answer as "line-breaks" does (which I did not know was a requirement). So I retagged the question again, to get the 5 reputation for "newline". Now I cannot add the synonym because "Reverse synonym has already been proposed".

A little research here on meta showed, that the problem might be related to the fact that both tags already have synonyms (sorry I cannot find the specific question any more to link it). So... could a moderator do that manually? Because both tags have a few hundred questions, or about one to two questions a day, while they are actually the same.

And in general, is there a better way to solve these cases? I mean, in a case like this anyone can spot that the two are the same, whether you have a score of 5 there or not. And even if there is this requirement, if I have a score of 5 in one of them, I should be able to propose the synonym in both directions. And lastly, I think it should be possible to propose the synonym at all.

Has this been discussed extensively somewhere? Because I can only find individual questions that were never properly answered.

Comment: While we're on the topic, can we please get rid of the useless [tag:linebreak] and [tag:linebreaks] synonyms to [tag:line-breaks]!?

Comment: A related topic [Does the tag synonym suggestion system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127459/does-the-tag-synonym-suggestion-system-work)

Comment: You're a mod now @animuson :-).

Comment: Funny this question got closed as off-topic, because I *did* originally ask it on MSO (I don't think MSE existed  two years ago). Anyway, if someone could migrate it back to MSO, that would be great, because it's still relevant there.

Comment: @MartinBüttner If it's still relevant (two years later), it's best to just post a new question.

Comment: @AnnaLear Well it's still relevant in that it never was addressed, so I'm not sure it's more likely to get fixed if I repost the exact same question now. If no one else bothered in those two years, then I guess it's not *that* important.

Answer (score 4):

Oh the irony. This is the tag wiki for [newline](/questions/tagged/newline)

> Newline refers to a character sequence representing a line break in
>   text (also known as End of Line, EOL, or Line Break). Different
>   operating systems have different sequences for newlines.

So, [eol](/questions/tagged/eol) and [end-of-line](/questions/tagged/end-of-line) should probably also be included in this and synonymised with [newline](/questions/tagged/newline).

Having done a bit of extra searching:

[line-endings](/questions/tagged/line-endings) seems to be being used as a synonym of newline as well.

---

I've just merged [line-feeds](/questions/tagged/line-feeds) into [linefeed](/questions/tagged/linefeed) (it was a lot smaller and it should be [line-feed](/questions/tagged/line-feed) anyway) but everything else seems to be as bad as it was.

Current counts:

- [eol](/questions/tagged/eol) - 102
- [end-of-line](/questions/tagged/end-of-line) - 37
- [line-endings](/questions/tagged/line-endings) - 122
- [line-breaks](/questions/tagged/line-breaks) - 555
- I've also cleared up the ones for people who can't tell the difference from [end-of-life](/questions/tagged/end-of-life)... not really sure if this should exist or not but that's another question.

On a related subject the following should probably also be synonyms/merged:

- [lines](/questions/tagged/lines) -> [line](/questions/tagged/line)
- [pagebreak](/questions/tagged/pagebreak) -> [page-break](/questions/tagged/page-break)
- [lf](/questions/tagged/lf) -> [linefeed](/questions/tagged/linefeed)

Comment: I'm tempted to add `[lf]` to this as well but it doesn't mean _exactly_ the same thing.